# Ansible set_fact array and populate it from in loop

Tags: ansible

I want to create an array and insert value from the the array `IP_TO_DNS` to reversed IP address.

The idea is to restructure the IP address given in the argument to be matchable later in my code.

**Code**

```
- name: create array reversed
  set_fact: reversed_ip=[]

- name: set convert ips from cli to matchable reversed ip
  set_fact: reversed_ip='{{ item | regex_replace('^(?P<first_range>\d{1,3})\.(?P<second_range>\d{1,3})\.(?P<third_range>\d{1,3})\.', 'named.\\g<third_range>.\\g<second_range>.\\g<first_range>')}}'
  with_items: '{{IP_TO_DNS}}'

- name: Match first block of results in path name
  debug: var=item
  with_items: '{{reversed_ip}}'
```

**Output**

```
TASK [dns : set convert ips from cli to matchable reversed ip] *****************
ok: [10.1.10.5] => (item=10.1.10.1)
ok: [10.1.10.5] => (item=10.1.10.2)
ok: [10.1.10.5] => (item=10.1.10.3)

TASK [dns : Match first block of results in path name] *************************
ok: [10.1.10.5] => (item=named.10.1.103) => {
    "item": "named.10.1.103"
}
```

It look like my variable is not set as an array and only the first value is populate.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting the same fact three times and it gets overwritten.

You should register the output:

```
- name: set convert ips from cli to matchable reversed ip
  set_fact: reversed_ip='{{ item | regex_replace('^(?P<first_range>\d{1,3})\.(?P<second_range>\d{1,3})\.(?P<third_range>\d{1,3})\.', 'named.\\g<third_range>.\\g<second_range>.\\g<first_range>')}}'
  with_items: '{{IP_TO_DNS}}'
  register: reversed_ip_results_list

- name: Match first block of results in path name
  debug: var=item.ansible_facts.reversed_ip
  with_items: '{{reversed_ip_results_list.results}}'
```

or if you want a list:

```
- debug: msg="{{ reversed_ip_results_list.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.reversed_ip') | list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks techraf that's doing the jobs.

Answer (score 10):

This is the one of the ways which I used

```
vars:
   my_new_list: []
tasks:
 - name: Get list of elements from list_vars
   set_fact:
     my_new_list: "{{ my_new_list + [item] }}"
  with_items: "{{ list_vars }}"
```

Comment: You don't need the `vars:` part if you set up the fact like this: `my_new_list: "{{ my_new_list | default([]) | union([item]) }}"`.

Comment: In such a case you'll get the empty element `[""]` as a part of the list. I've cleaned it up with: `list: "{{ list | default([]) | union(['list_element']) | difference(['']) }}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the default of reversed_ip as a list and append the item to the list.

```
- name: set convert ips from cli to matchable reversed ip
  set_fact: reversed_ip='{{ reversed_ip |default([]) + [item | regex_replace('^(?P<first_range>\d{1,3})\.(?P<second_range>\d{1,3})\.(?P<third_range>\d{1,3})\.', 'named.\\g<third_range>.\\g<second_range>.\\g<first_range>')] }}'
  with_items: "{{ IP_TO_DNS }}"

- name: Match first block of results in path name
  debug: var=item
  with_items: '{{reversed_ip}}'
```

Comment: Answers which contains only code are not considered complete. Plese read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer